# Конструкция с "исходя из"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Премия каждому конкретному сотруднику может выплачиваться за месяц, квартал и год(,) исходя из результатов его деятельности.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Выражение не совсем корректно (хотя в канцелярской практике сравнительно часто встречается), поскольку у деепричастия и глагола, к которому оно относится, производитель действия один и тот же. В результате его поиска оказывается, что *премия* выплачивает сама себя и *исходит* при этом из названных соображений. Если же изменить "может выплачиваться" на "(премию) можно/следует выплачивать", то предложение становится возможным (кто-то, соотв. службы выплачивают... исходя из...).

Подобные отклонения от нормы встречались в классической литературе (напр. у Тургенева), но их относят к галлицизмам (явлениям, вызванных неосознанным влиянием грамматики французского языка).

2. Что касается запятой. В перестроенном предложении

> Премию за месяц, квартал и год каждому конкретному сотруднику выплачивают, исходя из результатов его деятельности.

запятая **нужна**:

> ... оборот со словами *исходя из* обособляется, если относится к
> производителю действия, который может «исходить из чего-то»
> *Налогом
> облагают, исходя из установленных ставок* (Розенталь, Справочник по
> русскому языку. Орфография и пунктуация)
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=136#pp136)

Если же к имеющемуся галлицизму отнестись либерально (даже у Розенталя встречаются подобные примеры), то оборот можно не рассматривать как деепричастный, приписав выражению *исходя из* значение *на основании*. Тогда при изменённом порядке слов запятая была бы не нужна:

> Премия за месяц, квартал и год каждому конкретному сотруднику может
> выплачиваться исходя из результатов его деятельности.

В исходном же варианте есть два основания для постановки знака препинания перед *исходя из*: после перечисления, не заканчивающего предложение, обычно ставится *тире*; с другой стороны, по смыслу рассматриваемый оборот может трактоваться как элемент перечисления (одно из обстоятельств, регламентирующих порядок выплаты премии по срокам и размерам), поэтому при таком порядке слов есть основание для *запятой*:

> Премия каждому конкретному сотруднику может выплачиваться за месяц,
> квартал и год, исходя из результатов его деятельности.